# How to use a proxy for cocoa pods

Tags: proxy, appcode

How can I use a proxy for loading cocoapods, something like

```
export http_proxy='http://myserver:8080'
```

I did see the Http Proxy setting, but I'm not sure which setting to use with which string.

Comment: Do you want to have proxy only for cocoapods or for the whole system?

Comment: Thanks - I found a way. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case this did it

```
git config --global http.proxy http://myserver:8080
```

Comment: this worked for cocoapods < 1.0. since 1.0 i would expect the export http_proxy would work, but also that doesn't for me. anyone?

Answer (score 3):

This is what it works for me:

```
ALL_PROXY=http://myserver:8080 pod install
```